# How to duplicate features based on attribute value pyshp?

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp, duplication

I have a shapefile in which there are a series of polygons that I have to attribute to the name of a project which are recorded in 6 attribute fields. 
For each polygon there might be one to 6 projects associated. 
I need for each instance of a project name to have one polygon (up to 6 identical but for the name of the project) associated so that I can later dissolve the polygons according to the projects names.

I've used the pyshp module but I encounter a problem with the writing of the new polygon shapes based on the existing polygons. I read the existing using shapes[i].parts but it returs [0] to most of the shapes. Could you please give me a hand solving this issue ?

Here is my code :

```
import shapefile


#### Set input and target feature
inputShp = r"Pre-treatment\FP_BVC_Polygons.shp"
targShp= "Pre-treatment\FP_BVC_Polygons_test"
sf= shapefile.Reader(inputShp)
shapes= sf.shapes()
records = sf.records()

fields=sf.fields
w=shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)

for i in range(0,len(records)):
    for j in range(12,19):
        if records[i][j] != "0":
            listGeom.append(list(shapes[i].points))
            listRecord.append(records[i])

del i,j

for i in range(0, len(listGeom)):
    w.poly(points=listGeom[i])


for i in range(0,len(fields)):
    w.field(fields[i][0],fields[i][1],fields[i][2],fields[i][3])


for rec in listRecord:
    w.record(rec[0],rec[1],rec[2],rec[3],rec[4],rec[5],rec[6],rec[7],rec[8],
         rec[9],rec[10],rec[11],rec[12],rec[13],rec[14],rec[15],rec[16],rec[17],rec[18])

w.save(targShp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your script

To extract specific rows from values ( `if records[i][j] != "0":`)

```
import shapefile
sf= shapefile.Reader("polygons.shp")
fields = sf.fields[1:] 
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
w.fields = fields
for rec in sf.shapeRecords():
   if rec.record[3] > 0:
      w.records.append(rec.record)
      w._shapes.append(rec.shape)
w.save("duplicate")
```

You can also use a dictionary

```
field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]
for rec in sf.shapeRecords():
    atr = dict(zip(field_names, rec.record))
    if atr['test'] > 0:
       ....
```

If you want to select columns in a new shapefile

```
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
fields2 = [fields[1], fields[3]]
w.fields = fields2
for rec in sf.shapeRecords():
   if rec.record[3] > 0:
       w.records.append([rec.record[1],rec.record[3]])
       w._shapes.append(rec.shape)
w.save("duplicate2")
```

If you want to add a new field

```
fields = sf.fields[1:] 
fields2 = [fields[1], fields[3]]
# new field
fields2.append(['test', 'N', 10, 0])
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
w.fields = fields2
for rec in sf.shapeRecords():
   if rec.record[3] > 0:
       w.records.append([rec.record[1],rec.record[3], 3])
       w._shapes.append(rec.shape)
w.save("duplicate3")
```

Comment: Thank you so much I managed to do what I wanted. Here is my code based on your suggestion : `import shapefile

## Set input and target feature
inputShp = r"Polygons.shp"
targShp= "Polygons_test"

sf= shapefile.Reader(inputShp)
fields = sf.fields[1:]

w=shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
w.fields = fields

for rec in sf.shapeRecords():
   for i in range(12,19):
       if rec.record[i] != "0":
            w.records.append(rec.record)
            w._shapes.append(rec.shape)

w.save(targShp)`